# How to use json array length in angular?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, angularjs

my pages uses lots of ng-repeat to generate table rows. If there is no data in an json array, there would be an empty table. I'm trying to skip generating table rather than an generate an empty one.

To do that, I need to check if the array length is 0. In js  I can get array length using its length property:

```
$scope.data.errors.length === 0
```

But I can't use it in angular watcher, the following has no output

```
{{data.errors.length}}
```

And `data.errors.length === 0`gives false.

So is there a way to get json array length in angular?

Comment: Can you show more of the code?

Comment: have you tried just using `ng-if="data.errors"` in the tables parent

Comment: Have you tried `$scope.data.length`?

Comment: you want to display table of `data` or `data.error`

Comment: ng-show="data.error.length > 0" works. Thanks and sorry for asking such a simple question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ***ng-show*** Ex.

```html
<div ng-show=data.errors> your html </div>
```

Or you can use ***ng-repeat*** following code will execute if there is an error

```html
   <div ng-repeat="error in data.errors"></div>
```